# Personal messaging on `TeX.SX`

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined

Is there a way to send personal messages to another user on `TeX.SX` for some aspect of a question you don't want to be made public?

Obviously I don't have the other user's email address and he doesn't have mine. So how do we do it?

Comment: I came across this answer elsewhere, which has grieved my heart, saying it is not possible... http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57538/177432

Tell me this is not true. Please...

Comment: This has been asked many times on the Stackoverflow Meta site, and always declined (with good reasons). If you really need a way to do get in touch with someone privately without sharing your email address, create a temporary email account and tell the other user the address in a comment.

Comment: I recommend reading [Shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/1438)'s excellent answer to a network-wide request for the same feature.  I've wanted to contact other user privately myself and found that exchanging emails (or even just one person publishing theirs) in chat works just fine.

Comment: Chat cannot be a solution when large time zone differences are involved. I've seen how interest in chat quickly fades away on other sites where the global nature of the situation makes it too difficult. PMs work well on other forums I frequent, I just cannot agree with the majority of the reasons I've seen against having them here. If anyone doesn't want them, a feature to turn them off in your profile is easy. The advantages of having them outweigh the disadvantages in all the cases I've seen. People talk to each other at work, at school or wherever in between - it's human.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My suggestion is to [invite this person to a personal chat](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3591/5764) (albeit public) where you can hash out some ideas and/or exchange details, since [similar requests have been declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537/168244) in the past. This way you're guaranteed to connect to the specific individual (if they have a chat account) rather than waiting for them to enter the [main chat area](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends), or via a comment to one of their posts.