# Undoing a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

On this [question about creating complicated tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164925/911), I wanted to award a +100 bounty on this [answer by user47919 involving the `tap` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165374/911).

In my haste, I accidentally awarded it to [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164962/911) instead. (I did read the warning about making sure it was the correct answer to award it to: it was the fifth such time that I read that warning, in fact, because I tried to award the bounty a few times, not having carefully kept track of precisely when it would be possible to award it.) While David is certainly a wonderfully helpful person on the site, I would really have preferred to award it to a user with lower reputation.

When I tried to offer another bounty to award it to them, however, I found the minumum bounty has risen to 200. (It appears as though each question can only be awarded one bounty of any given value!)

Is there any way for the mods to undo my bounty to David, and allow me to reward a +100 bounty to user47919 instead? Alternatively: can they shift the recipient of the bounty themselves?

Comment: I was waiting a day or two to see if it got moved. As I said if it doesn't move I'll award a bounty to the other answer, so you don't need to award two (unless you want to:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It seems that you putting another bounty is the only reasonable way out of the situation. Maybe you can make it an answer here? :)

Comment: @tohecz answer added

Answer (score 10):

Despite the fact that I'm sure all my answers are worth bounties, it seems that the only way to move bounties is for the allegedly undeserving recipient to award a bounty of an equivalent amount to the allegedly more deserving recipient. Accordingly I have started a bounty on the referenced question and will award it once the system allows, later today.

Answer (score 7):

While there is no way for mods to *transfer* bounties between recipients, one option is to [ping the user in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14393188#14393188) and explain the situation<sup>*</sup>. Chat rooms are a great way to connect to people directly, even in a group session on [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends). Alternatively, [invite them to a private chat room](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3591/5764).

Another approach would be to "suck it up" and find another answer of the person you originally intended the bounty for, and issue it with a custom clause...

<sub><sup>*</sup> This solution approach may be very particular to [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) where the community is more accepting of regular social behaviour as opposed to the cut-throat anonymity of (say) [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Mods can't reverse bounties. This will have to be raised with the StackExchange staff: presumably it is doable with direct access to the 'back end': use the [Contact Us](https://tex.stackexchange.com/contact) form to do this.

Comment: In [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127828/168244), a mod mentions that a bounty can be reversed (or refunded) by mods. Is this specific to mods on [so]?

Comment: @Werner That's reversing _before_ award: we can remove the 'promotion' of questions and send the bounty back to the 'donor', a power that is reserved for very limited occasions. Once its  awarded, however, we are powerless.