# "Help Center > Privileges > create chat rooms" `invite` room menu option missleading?

Tags: discussion

I think relatively new users get a bit confused when they read on the page [Help Center > Privileges > create chat rooms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms), that after creating a new chat room I can invite someone "using the `invite` room menu option.

I just created the first time a new room and was searching that menu option, but couldn't find it. Where can I find that option? But reading a bit on the meta page I think there is only a "fast" invite option for people already being in a chat like in [this answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3673/95441), right?

If so, I recommend to adapt the text below the item "What happens when I create a new room?" to something similar as mentioned [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3592/95441). That would it make much clearer that (non-chat)TeX.SX and chat.TeX.SX are somewhat different "rooms"/"features" (sorry, don't find the right words).

Comment: Is that not [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPzu5.png)?

Comment: Not in my list. I see there `full transcript`, `create new bookmark`, `Room owner`, `schedule events`, `control access`, `manage feeds`, and `move messages`.

Comment: For me, the option has disappeared. Or else I can no longer find it. I have used it in the past, but I can't use it anymore.

Comment: @cfr, that is very interesting that there really _was_ this option. Now the question is, has it disappeared by intention or os it a bug.

Comment: No idea. It only struck me because I couldn't find it the other day, but I'm sure I've used it in the past. It was quite convenient, though I don't use chat rooms often so I can't rule out my just not being able to find it now.